# GDAL, Python, pyramids/statistics read/write

Tags: python, raster, gdal, erdas-imagine

As I work through learning programing with raster imagery, I am trying to read in a raster, change the pixel values and write the output file. Below is the code. I have blocked out the change pixel values as my output file was empty and in the wrong location, so I am now trying to just read in a file by block and write out the same file. However  the file I get is defaulted to the 64/64 block size, and my skip factor is 999, so my output raster does not 'match' my input raster. I have not been able to SET the metadata changes. Can someone tell me the correct way in a script to set new metadata options, and then I will need the numpy.where to process correctly?

```
import os, sys, ogr, gdal, utils, numpy
from gdalconst import *

file = (r'C:\Users\Desktop\images\large_raster.img')

gdal.AllRegister()

ds = gdal.Open(file, GA_ReadOnly)
if ds is None:
    print 'Could not open file'
    sys.exit(1)

rows = ds.RasterYSize
cols = ds.RasterXSize
bands = ds.RasterCount

band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

yBlocksize = 512
xBlocksize = 512
count = 0

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('HFA')
metadata = driver.GetMetadata()

#print metadata

outfile = (r'C:\Users\aschilli\Desktop\images\chrisG_test2.img')

outDataset = driver.Create(outfile, cols, rows, 1)

outBand = outDataset.GetRasterBand(1)
outBand.FlushCache()
outBand.SetNoDataValue(-99) #this gives 0
outDataset.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
outDataset.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection()) 
gdalinfo = (r"C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Scripts\new_ve_folder\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalinfo.exe")
command = gdalinfo + ' -hist ' + ' -stats ' + outfile
os.system(command)
gdaladdo = (r"C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Scripts\new_ve_folder\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdaladdo.exe")
command2 = gdaladdo + ' --config ' ' HFA_USE_RRD ' ' YES ' + outfile + ' 3 9 27 81'
os.system(command2)
#this code below does nothing
outDataset.SetMetadataItem({
    'BLOCKSIZE': '512/512',
    'STATISTICS': 'TRUE',
    'DMD_CREATIONDATATYPES': 'Int16'
})

#loop through rows
for i in range(0, rows, yBlocksize):
    if i + yBlocksize < rows:
        numRows = yBlocksize
    else:
        numRows = rows - i
#loop through coloumns
    for j in range(0, cols, xBlocksize):
        if j + xBlocksize < cols:
            numCols = xBlocksize
        else:
            numCols = cols - j

    #read data and do calculations
        data = band.ReadAsArray(j, i,  numCols, numRows)
        # out_data = numpy.where(abs(data) < 500, 10, data)

        outBand.WriteArray(data, j, i)

del outDataset

#http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160578/write-python-ndarray-to-raster?'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out and gotten to work one part of my statistics issue.
src_ds = gdal.Open(outfile)
outBand.SetMetadataItem("LAYER_TYPE", "thematic")
outBand.SetMetadataItem("STATISTICS", "YES")

This will give me my skip factor of 1 for ERDAS img files.

My file only writes out the first block of data, so I am missing something telling my script to write out BY block and not just the first block.

Comment: adding < outBand.SetMetadataItem("BLOCKSIZE", "512/512")>  solved the problem of only writing first block. I have gotten most of this to work, now for some really detailed reclassifying.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit convoluted. I gather that you are trying to classify an image using a *numpy.where* statement, and are having problems setting the correct georeferencing on the output image. From your script, I can also see that you are reading only the first raster band in GDAL, so I am assuming that your input raster has only one band.

The following code will accomplish what you want. The commands *OutRaster.SetProjection()* and *OutRaster.SetGeoTransform()* set the georeferencing of your output raster:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy

InputImage = 'ImageName.tif'
OutImage = 'OutImageName.tif'
gdalformat = 'GTiff'
########################################################################
print("Opening "+InputImage+"...")
Dataset = gdal.Open(InputImage, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
XSize = Dataset.RasterXSize
YSize = Dataset.RasterYSize
Projection = Dataset.GetProjectionRef()
GeoTransform = Dataset.GetGeoTransform()

Band1 = Dataset.GetRasterBand(1) # Select band 1 to read as numpy array
Array = Band1.ReadAsArray()
Dataset = None # Closes the input image

# Create an empty duplicate numpy array.  
Classification = numpy.empty_like(Array, dtype='uint8')

print("Perfoming classification...")
Classification = numpy.where((Array <= 500), 1, Classification)
Classification = numpy.where((Classification != 1) & (Array > 500), 2, Classification)
Array = None # Close the input array

# Create the output raster
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(gdalformat)
metadata = driver.GetMetadata()
OutRaster = driver.Create(OutImage, XSize, YSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte) # (OutImageName, XSize, YSize, Image bands, datatype)
OutRaster.SetProjection(Projection)
OutRaster.SetGeoTransform(GeoTransform)

# Write classification to band 1
OutBand = OutRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
OutBand.SetNoDataValue(0)
OutBand.WriteArray(Classification)

# Close the datasets
OutRaster, OutBand, Classification = None, None, None
print("Done.")
```

I don't know why you are trying to read the raster in blocks - perhaps because the raster is very large? In this case, you could tile the image and classify each tile before mosaicking them back together. Alternatively, you could use something like [rios](http://rios-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which can read the raster in chunks rather than loading the entire image into memory.